# Images from data model are not loading into Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, image, bootstrap-modal

On my page I loaded images into a carousel.  The images are loading from the data model.  The inspected view of the image shows the data-img-url has a complete url.  When I click on the image the modal will open but there is no image.  What correction should I make so the image renders in the modal window?  Below is the html...

```
<ul id="sync1">
    <li class="item">
        @*This is the primary image*@
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-img-url="@Model.ImageLargePath">
            <img src="@Model.ImageLargePath" data-src="@Model.ImageLargePath" alt="@(Model.Attributes?.Value("SEODescription"))" title="@Model.SEODescription" class="carousel-img" />
        </a>
        <a class="carouselImageText">@(Model.SEODescription.ToString())</a>
    </li>
    @if (Model.AlternateImages != null && Model.AlternateImages.Any())
    {
        //This is where we load all the images into the primary carousel IF we have alternate images
        foreach (var image in Model.AlternateImages)
        {
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-img-url="@Model.ImageLargePath">
                    <img src="@image.ImageLargePath" class="carousel-img" />
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Here is the modal...

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img class="" src="#" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript...

```
$('#sync1 img').click(function (e) {
    $('#myModal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url'));
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(e).attr('data-img-url)`?

Comment: @VincentNguyen  thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: Log to the console what $(this).attr('data-img-url) and $(e).attr('data-img-url) each return to you

Comment: they both return "http://localhost:3288/Content/Images/no-image.png"

Comment: And is that the correct path to where your image is located?

Comment: No it isn't...the inspected element on the page shows 'data-img-url="http://localhost:44762/Data/Media/Catalog/1/asparagus.jpg"'

Comment: Oh try `$(this).attr('data-src')`

Comment: hmmm...that actually worked but not matter which image I click it is the first image that loads...in every modal

Comment: Well from your HTML it seems you only have one `<li>` item so there's only one image I can see

Comment: You answered the question...I will try to solve this new problem.  Thanks for your help.